# Error in Parallelization process with the function clusterR: cluster error

Tags: r, multithreading, extract, raster

I want to extract the values in the *RasterLayer* `t` by the *sf* object `Continent.list[[c]]`, so I wrote the code below and it works:

```
Month.Continent.value <- extract(t, Continent.list[[c]])
```

Because my raster file is super large, it took many hours to finish this process. Therefore, I want to use the multithreading method to promote the efficiency of running the `extract` function. I encounter an error when I want to use the `clusterR` function. The problematic code is below:

```
beginCluster(4)    
Month.Continent.value <- clusterR(t, extract, args = list(y = Continent.list[[c]]))
```

And the error message showed up:

```
Error in clusterR(t, extract, args = list(y = Continent.list[[c]])) : 
  cluster error
```

I can't figure out what does this mean. Did I rewrite my function in a wrong way? I try to search for an explanation. Some people also have the problem when using `extract` in `clusterR`, but it seems that not many people have the same type of error message as me. Any suggestion is good for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your original problem was the extraction speed, the best solution is to switch to one of these 2 packages: `terra` (which is the new version of `raster` and will substitute it) and `exactextractr`. The latter is way faster than any other solution you can find to extract raster values from polygons (unfortunately it works only with polygon data, not points. But you can use a buffer in that case).
Here I show you a little benchmark:

```
library(raster)
library(terra)
library(sf)
library(exactextractr)
# Pull municipal boundaries for Brazil
ita<- st_as_sf(getData('GADM', country='ITA', level=1))
# Pull raster precipitation data
prec <- getData('worldclim', var='prec', res=10)

#my machine has 12 core and 16 Gb RAM
#extract values just for 1 layer
system.time(mean_prec_ras <- raster::extract(prec[[12]],ita,fun=mean))# 7.86
system.time(mean_prec_ras <- terra::extract(prec[[12]],ita,fun=mean))#7.58 sec
system.time(mean_prec <- exact_extract(prec[[12]], ita, fun='mean'))#0.55 sec
```